# "comes from the French word meaning..."

Tags: grammar

Consider the sentence

> The name *ratatouille* comes from the French word *touiller*, meaning to stir or mix together.

The part after the comma starts with the word *meaning*. Do I need to put double quotation marks or italicize "to stir or mix together"?

Comment: @Chappo updated

Comment: Comment deleted, and downvote removed, although it remains a somewhat trivial question. You don't need to do either, but either is acceptable. In other words, any one of the three options (quotation marks, italics or nothing) is fine - it comes down to a matter of *style*, so if a particular style manual applies, you should consult that.

Comment: Normally you do not put the *explanation* in quotation marks or italics. In fact I'd say that *isn't* commonly acceptable. Only the word being mentioned goes in quotation marks or italics. Sometimes the explanation is put in parentheses: the French word *touiller* (to stir or mix together). But prefacing it with *, meaning* is also fine.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks a lot -- if that were an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: Done. It took me a bit to expand it into something I thought was a complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering the question, I want to give a bit of background.

When referring to a word as a word, it's normal to put it in quotation marks (double or single) or to put it in italics.

So, we could write:

> The name "ratatouille" comes from the French word "touiller."
> The name 'ratatouille' comes from the French word 'touiller'.
> The name *ratatouille* comes from the French word *touiller*.

(In the second example, where I used single quotation marks, I also used British-style punctuation by putting the period after the final quotation mark—because the period is not part of what's being quoted. *The Chicago Manual of Style* gives guidance that this is acceptable in the US if single quotation marks are being used to signal words as words in the context of science or literary criticism.)

Outside of referencing a word as a word, quotation marks are used to signal that something has been spoken or written by somebody else and that you are actually providing a quote. (Or simply indicating direct dialogue in the case of fiction.)

Sometimes, quotation marks can be used as so-called scare quotes, where what is inside the quotation marks is not *literal* but something that is being referred to in a sarcastic manner.

---

As with how to represent a word as a word, the way of providing the meaning for something is a matter of style. It will change from person to person and style guide to style guide.

I could say that *meaning* [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meaning) "the thing one intends to convey especially by language." In that sentence, I put the final part in quotation marks because I was *quoting* the Merriam-Webster definition of the first sense of *meaning*.

Let's say I do the same thing with your sentence:

> The name *ratatouille* comes from the French word *touiller*, meaning "to stir or mix together."

If I read that, my first thought is to wonder where that quotation came from—what person said it or what cookbook or dictionary wrote it. But there is no attribution given. Quoting someone or something and not providing an attribution can lead to both puzzlement and issues of plagiarism.

In this case, there is no actual quotation. But the use of the quotation marks, as they were used, suggests that there should have been.

If the sentence had been written differently, then there wouldn't have been any possible misunderstanding:

> The name "ratatouille" comes from the French word "touiller". It means the same thing as the phrase "to stir or mix things together."

Here, I've already used quotation marks to signal words as words in the first part of the sentence and I'm signalling a similar intention in the second part by using the word *phrase* immediately before providing the phrase in quotation marks.

The only problem with this is one of semantics. I'm not *actually* referring to a phrase. Instead, I'm simply using words combined together to express something as I would in any other sentence.

The use of italics would lead to a similar problem because italics either refer to words as words or provide emphasis.

In this case, *to stir or mix together* is not being given as words as words, as a quotation, as a phrase, in a sarcastic manner, or in any kind of emphatic way. In other words, it should likely be presented in plain Roman text without quotation marks.

---

There are two common methods of styling your sentence.

One is to precede its final words with *meaning*, as you already have.

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 6.96, points to another common method:

> Parentheses are used to enclose glosses of unfamiliar terms or translations from other languages—or, if the term is given in English, to enclose the original word. In quoted matter, brackets should be used.
>
> A drop folio (a page number printed at the foot of a page) is useful on the opening page of a chapter.
>
> The term you should use for 1,000,000,000 is *mil millones* (billion), not *billón* (trillion).
>
> German has two terms for eating—one for the way humans eat (*essen*) and another for the way animals eat (*fressen*).

So, the following are both possibilities for your sentence:

> The name *ratatouille* comes from the French word *touiller*, meaning to stir or mix together.
> The name *ratatouille* comes from the French word *touiller* (to stir or mix together).